# How to redirect my user after posting a comment

Tags: python, django, blogs

So I just learned how to add comments on my blog. Now the problem is that I can't redirect my user to the concerned blog post. That's really frustrating because I see a lot of people on the Internet talking about get_absolute_url and it confuses me a lot.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Annonce, Comments
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def annonceView(request, annonce_id):
    annonce = get_object_or_404(Annonce, pk=annonce_id)
    comments = Comments.objects.filter(auteur=annonce_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST["add_comment"]
        if content:
        new_comment = Comments.objects.create(content=content, auteur=annonce)
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect(annonce)

    context = {
        "annonce": annonce,
        "comments": comments,
    }

    return render(request, "annonces/annonce.html", context)
```

Comment: Would you like to correct your indentation? What you've posted doesn't make sense.

Comment: @khelwood i just changed it

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can use a [**`get_absolute_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) here. You can add such method to a model, for example:

```
# app/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Annonce(models.Model):

    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('annonce_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Here `annonce_detail` is the name of a hypothetical view, so in your `urls.py`, we then have a path like:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('annonce/<int:pk>', views.annonce_detail, name='annonce_detail'),
    # ...
]
```

This means that for a given `Annonce` object, we can ask `some_annonce.get_absolute_url()`, and it will respond with something like `/annonce/123`.

Now [**`redirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) takes model objects with a `get_absolute_url` into account. Indeed, as the documentation says:

> Returns an `HttpResponseRedirect` to the appropriate URL for the
>   arguments passed.
>
> The arguments could be:
>
> - A **model**: the **model's `get_absolute_url()` function** will be called.
> - A view name, possibly with arguments: `reverse()` will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
> - An absolute or relative URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.
>
> By default issues a temporary redirect; pass `permanent=True` to issue
>   a permanent redirect.

If you thus have defined such `get_absolute_url` on that model, you can pass that object to `redirect`, like:

```
def annonceView(request, annonce_id):
    annonce = get_object_or_404(Annonce, pk=annonce_id)
    comments = Comments.objects.filter(auteur=annonce_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST["add_comment"]
        if content:
        new_comment = Comments.objects.create(content=content, auteur=annonce)
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect(annonce)

    context = {
        "annonce": annonce,
        "comments": comments,
    }

    return render(request, "annonces/annonce.html", context)
```

> **Note**: models typically have *singular* names, so `Comment`, *not* `Comments`.

> **Note**: you might want to consider [working with *forms* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) since the given input is not per se valid, and a form can do proper validation, as well as removing a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. So the key is that get_absolute_url method. But i was so confused about the kwargs={"pk": self.pk}, but i guess that it is just a way ton tell Django that we are working with a specific annonce. I will also consider working with django Forms instead of html forms. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a object to redirect.

```
return redirect(annonce)
```

But the function accepts a string:

```
return redirect("https://www.google.com")
```

If you have a specific url in urls that you wanna redirect:

```
urlpatterns = [ path("example/", views.ExampleView.as_view(), name="example_view") ]

return redirect(reverse("example_view"))
```

Comment: The [`redirect` function also accepts a model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) whose `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.